# truncate fastq.gz file without error in Snakemake

Tags: snakemake

All,

As the first step in my Snakemake pipeline, I generate small fastq files from all input fastq.gz files. This is to run a quick round of "infer_experiment.py" (from RSeQC, to get the kit strandedness). However, Snakemake says this step fails. I think I know why, it is because a command like this

```
zcat fastq_raw/20190011-043_S43_R1_001.fastq.gz | head -n 400000 > infer_strandedness/20190011-043_S43_subset_R1.fastq
```

Ends with an error: `gzip: stdout: Broken pipe` and Snakemake uses Bash strict mode. (Snakemake reports: `(one of the commands exited with non-zero exit code; note that snakemake uses bash strict mode!)`). So my question is:

How to avoid this, or, are there other truncating methods that do finish cleanly? Preferebly they are also efficient (seqtk offers subsampling but this parses the entire fastq file!).

Comment: You're better off using seqtk even if it's slower since you're then not performing a highly biased sampling from the beginning of the file, where the quality tends to be worse.

Comment: But the library is randomized during prep and flowing into the chip, why would the first part of the fastq file (first scanned tile of the chip) be biased? A bit worse quality would not be a problem if I only want to detect the strandedness...

Comment: The beginning of the files represent the edge of the flow cell where the quality is lower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snakemake is using bash strict mode to ensure best practice error reporting in shell commands. Unfortunately some tools violate bash strict mode.

More details of the error, [here](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/project_info/faq.html#my-shell-command-fails-with-exit-code-0-from-within-a-pipe-what-s-wrong). Alternatively, you can use if you don't want disable the strict mode.

```
zcat file.fastq.gz  | awk '(NR<=400000)' > subset.fastq
```

Comment: This solves my problem exactly (the awk solution), it is fast and does what my original command does but without pipefail error. Thank you.

Comment: @Freek another option would be to add `|| true` to give a 0 exit status